# Redirect Express.js HTTP to HTTPS on the same port

Tags: node.js, express

During development I would like to start up two instances of my server.js (app.js) script which uses the http and https modules, a route redirect (`*`) to https and running in say port `3000` for one instance and another on port `3001`. Now if I do a port `80` to port `443` I have no problems except that I have to start the script with `sudo` and I can only have one instance. Is there a way to accomplish this where http can redirect to https on the same port.

```
application.get('*', function(request, response, next) {
    if (!request.secure) {
        response.redirect('https://' + request.headers.host + request.url);
    } else {
        next();
    }
});

http
    .createServer(application)
    .listen(80, function() {
        var uid = parseInt(process.env.SUDO_UID);
        if (uid) {
            process.setuid(uid);
        }
    });
https
    .createServer({
        key: fs.readFileSync(...),
        cert: fs.readFileSync(...)
    }, application)
    .listen(443, function() {
        var uid = parseInt(process.env.SUDO_UID);
        if (uid) {
            process.setuid(uid);
        }
        console.log(
            'Express server running in %s environment at %s',
            process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development',
            moment()
        );
    });
```

Comment: You can't run two different servers on the same port...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep your port in ENV variable, then use it to listen and redirect methods.